# How to keep selected rows and delete other from the jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rows, defaulttablemodel

I want to keep all the selected rows in the jtable and delete the rest of them. I found many answers regarding how to delete the selected rows but how can I delete the non selected rows only. Please help

Comment: Save the selected rows -> delete all rows -> re-add the saved/selected

Comment: I try to do so using vectors but it gives errors.

Comment: What errors does it show?

Comment: you probably can use one of those answers for deleting the selected rows and adjust it for you by adding some nots ! at the correct places to fit your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a more convenient way which works perfectly fine with all possible cases.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int[] lines = table.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(lines[i]);
    }
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : lines) {
        l.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!l.contains(i)) {
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it could be slimmed down a bit or a bit code could be moved to an own method which makes it look cleaner, but its working

Comment: `I think it could be slimmed down a bit` - yes, there is no need to worry about the array of selected rows. The indexes of the selected rows are automatically updated as your add/remove rows from the model. So you just need to start at the end of the table and work backwards.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips:

1. Don't worry about the array of selected rows. The indexes of the selected rows is automatically adjusted as your add/remove a row from the model. Just start deleting rows from the end checking the selected state of each row as you go.
2. Convert the view index to the model index in case the table is sorted or filtered.

Then the basic code is:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

for (int i = model.getRowCount() -1; i >=0; i--)
{
    if (! table.isRowSelected(i))
        model.removeRow( table.convertRowIndexToModel(i) );
}
```

Comment: you can remove `int row = table.getSelectedRow();`

Answer (score 0):

I could not test it at all, but i hope it helps:

```
public void removeSelectedRows(JTable table){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
    int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
    int rowsCount = table.getRowCount();
    int deletedRows = 0;
    for(int i=rowsCount-1;i>-1;i--){
        if(i!=rows[rowsCount-1-deletedRows]){ //Check non-selected rows
            model.removeRow(i);
            deletedRows++;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is an easiest way but this should work fine.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `model.removeRow(i);` removes row dynamically which means that no empty rows are saved. This would cause a problem if you select multiple rows which are not continuous as you would save rows which were not selected and remove the rows you actually selected. A safer approach would be to actually store the data of the rows, remove all rows and readd the ones oyu saved

Comment: I also tried a similar logic but it results the same "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: How about refreshing the array size in every delete operation? I don't think store the data we need, delete everything and writting the data again is a good idea because here probably we have got a few rows... if we have millions of rows... we have got a big problem of efficiency.

Comment: Right idea, but you don't need to worry about the array of selected rows. This is confusing the logic for the index in the if statement.